# How to return from link formatter url callback without making a hyperlink

Tags: tabulator

I am using the formatter:"link" url callback to generate a hyperlink for a certain column in my Tabulator table

```
tabulatorTable.addColumn({
    title: "Value",
    field: "JSONDoc.Path.To.Property",
    formatter: "link",
    formatterParams: {
        url: getHyperLink,
        target: "_blank"
    }
});
```

Then in my callback function:

```
function getHyperLink(cellComp) {
    var cellData = cellComp.getData();

    var propValFromJSONSource = cellData.SomeProperty;

    if( propValFromJSONSource != 0) {
        return "http://hostname/report/showLog.php?prop=" + propValFromJSONSource;
    }
    else {
        // If here, I can't generate a valid link, so I want to not have a hyperlink and just show the data
        return ???;
    }
}
```

Is there anything that I can do in the else statement to return from the formatter to instruct Tabulator to not create a hyperlink?

I've tried:

```
return "";  // This makes the hyperlink go to "<currentURL>"
return null; // This generates a relative hyperlink to "<currentURL>/null"
return undefined; // This generates a relative hyperlink to "<currentURL>/undefined"
```

I suspect I might not be able to use the link formatter and will need to switch to a custom formatter callback that returns "

I also have the problem of not being able to left-click on the hyperlink (even though it appears correctly down in the status bar); I can only center click or right-click and choose "Open in new tab".  I'm not sure if this a bug within Tabulator, or Chrome not understanding it for some reason, but that shall be another SO question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I'm recommending the use of a custom formatter:

```
tabulatorTable.addColumn({
    title: "Value",
    field: "JSONDoc.Path.To.Property",
    formatter: getHyperLink,
});
```

Then have the callback return the html code for a hyperlink or just text:

```
function getHyperLink(cellComp, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    var cellData = cellComp.getData();
    var cellValue = cellComp.getValue();

    var propValFromJSONSource = cellData.SomeProperty;

    if( propValFromJSONSource != 0) {
        var hrefString = "http://hostname/report/showLog.php?prop=" + propValFromJSONSource;
        return "<a href='" + hrefString + "' target='_blank'>" + cellValue + "</a>";
    }
    else {
        return cellValue;
    }
}
```